# How to run Grafana 6.x behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, grafana, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using Grafana behind a reverse proxy (NGINX). Version 5.x works with the following setup pretty well. Since I updated to version 6.x this configuration doesn't work any more. I can login, but Grafana directly logs me out. Does someone has any ideas?

**Workaround**

If I bind the Grafana to an IP address by `http_addr=192.168.1.200` in the grafana.ini file I can access (loging) to the dashboard by `192.168.1.200:3000`. The full domain name (FQDN) still fails.

**grafana.ini**

```
domain = grafana.xxx.local
root_url = http://grafana.xxx.local
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name grafana.xxx.local;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can exclude `nginx` from the equation if you bind `grafana` to your external interface. Does it work then?

Comment: Yes that works. But then I have to use the IP address directly and cannot not use the domain address.

Comment: You might want to add that info to your question text, because that's important information in that context. So you are saying that if you access grafana by IP it works and when you access it via the FQDN then it doesn't?